Race conditions in NodeJS when incrementing?
Using NodeJS and Express stack, is the below safe from race conditions?
NodeJS is single threaded, but not sure if the incoming requests are processed sequentially and if libuv impacts this at all.
Wondering whether this would be safe if millions of incoming requests would cause any side effects.
let number = 0;

app.post("/submitTransaction", (req, res) => {
  number++
  let result = await submitTransaction({seqNumber: number });
  return result;
}


Yes, the increment of number in that code is safe from race conditions. The code you've shown will only ever be running on one thread at a time. Also, yes, there's a (quite rare) need for atomic integer operations in Node.js (and other JS envs), but only if you're using shared memory across worker threads. That's why the functions on Atomics exist. You don't need them for your number variable.

node js's model is entirely different from what you see in other multithreaded languages ,firstly unless you are not creating cluster or worker threads there would be one process and one  single threaded event loop to handle all your requests so there is no chance to have race conditions ,unless you are using shared memory as mentioned in other comment by @T.J.Crowder

Thanks, appreciate the clear answers!
